# Struts 2 Action: parameter access

Tags: parameters, struts2

I defined an action like this:

```
<action name="login" class="tognetti.site.actions.AuthenticationAction">
 <param name="defaultURI">/secure/listaAnnunci.action</param>
    <result>/login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I can I access the param from inside the action?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the [Static Parameters interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/static-parameters-interceptor.html) my good man:

```
<action name="login" class="tognetti.site.actions.AuthenticationAction">
   <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
   <interceptor-ref name="staticParams">
      <param name="defaultURI">/secure/listaAnnunci.action</param>
   </interceptor-ref>
   <result>/login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Then have your Action implement `Parameterizable` and your param's will be added to the request params map.

Comment: Great! If I extend the struts-default package I have only to implement the interface. Thanks!